# SQL Select - Group by along with inner join?

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, inner-join, distinct

I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT TOP 12 
        INVENTABLE.ITEMNUMBER, 
        INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME1, 
        INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME2, 
        INVENTABLE.W_TILBUD, 
        INVENTABLE.COSTPRICE, 
        INVENTABLE.VENDITEMNUMBER, 
        INVENTABLE.A_PRODUCENT, 
        INVENTABLE.GROUP_, 
        INVENTABLE.A_GROSSISTLAGER, 
        INVENTABLE.SupplementaryUnits 

    FROM INVENTRANS

    INNER JOIN INVENTABLE ON INVENTABLE.ITEMNUMBER=INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER 

    WHERE   INVENTRANS.ACCOUNT='xxx'    AND 
            INVENTABLE.W_VISFORSIDE = 0 AND 
            INVENTABLE.W_VISWWW = 1     AND 
            INVENTABLE.BLOCKED = 0 

    ORDER BY INVENTRANS.ROWNUMBER DESC
```

This query selects the 12 last sold items from one table (INVENTRANS), and gets the item information from another (INVENTABLE). It works like it should, except I would like to prevent multiple of the same item (INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER) to be in the same result.

I have tried looking around for solutions and tried several examples with a DISTINCT or GROUP BY, but I haven't been able to make it work :/

Any help much appreciated! :)

**Solution:**

```
;WITH CTE AS (
       SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER 
                                 ORDER BY INVENTRANS.ROWNUMBER DESC) AS rn,
           INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER,
           INVENTRANS.ROWNUMBER,
           INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME1, 
           INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME2, 
           INVENTABLE.W_TILBUD, 
           INVENTABLE.COSTPRICE, 
           INVENTABLE.VENDITEMNUMBER, 
           INVENTABLE.A_PRODUCENT, 
           INVENTABLE.GROUP_, 
           INVENTABLE.A_GROSSISTLAGER, 
           INVENTABLE.SupplementaryUnits 
    FROM INVENTRANS
    INNER JOIN INVENTABLE ON INVENTABLE.ITEMNUMBER=INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER 
    WHERE   INVENTRANS.ACCOUNT='xxx'    AND 
            INVENTABLE.W_VISFORSIDE = 0 AND 
            INVENTABLE.W_VISWWW = 1     AND 
            INVENTABLE.BLOCKED = 0 
)
SELECT TOP 12 *
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ROWNUMBER DESC
```

Comment: if there are multiple rows for an item number then select only one of them so that all 12 rows should have different item numbers ? is that correct? if so then which one of multiples would you like to have in result set.

Comment: Can you show us an example of your data and what you want the query to return? Often times that is more helpful than trying to reverse engineer code while guessing at the table schema.

Comment: Never noticed the comments up here, apologies! Solution has been found and I will edit my post with the working code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` with a `PARTITION BY` clause to identify duplicates:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
   SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMNUMBER 
                              ORDER BY ROWNUMBER DESC) AS rn,
           INVENTABLE.ITEMNUMBER, 
           INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME1, 
           INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME2, 
           INVENTABLE.W_TILBUD, 
           INVENTABLE.COSTPRICE, 
           INVENTABLE.VENDITEMNUMBER, 
           INVENTABLE.A_PRODUCENT, 
           INVENTABLE.GROUP_, 
           INVENTABLE.A_GROSSISTLAGER, 
           INVENTABLE.SupplementaryUnits 
    FROM INVENTRANS
    INNER JOIN INVENTABLE ON INVENTABLE.ITEMNUMBER=INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER 
    WHERE   INVENTRANS.ACCOUNT='xxx'    AND 
            INVENTABLE.W_VISFORSIDE = 0 AND 
            INVENTABLE.W_VISWWW = 1     AND 
            INVENTABLE.BLOCKED = 0 
)
SELECT TOP 12 *
FROM CTE 
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ROWNUMBER DESC
```

Any record returned from `CTE` with `rn > 1` is a duplicate and is thus filtered out by the `WHERE` clause. Duplicate records filtered out are the ones having the lowest `ROWNUMBER` values. You can change the `ORDER BY` clause of `ROW_NUMBER` to change this criterion any way you like.

Comment: With a little tweaking I got it working :D Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GROUP BY INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER` (not in your inner join but in "main query") this will remove all dublicates of `ITEMNUMBER`..
`DISINCT` only removes completly identical sets.

```
SELECT TOP 12 
        INVENTABLE.ITEMNUMBER, 
        INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME1, 
        INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME2, 
        INVENTABLE.W_TILBUD, 
        INVENTABLE.COSTPRICE, 
        INVENTABLE.VENDITEMNUMBER, 
        INVENTABLE.A_PRODUCENT, 
        INVENTABLE.GROUP_, 
        INVENTABLE.A_GROSSISTLAGER, 
        INVENTABLE.SupplementaryUnits 
FROM INVENTRANS

INNER JOIN INVENTABLE ON INVENTABLE.ITEMNUMBER=INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER 

WHERE   INVENTRANS.ACCOUNT='xxx'    AND 
        INVENTABLE.W_VISFORSIDE = 0 AND 
        INVENTABLE.W_VISWWW = 1     AND 
        INVENTABLE.BLOCKED = 0 

GROUP BY INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER

ORDER BY INVENTRANS.ROWNUMBER DESC
```

Comment: Where would you want me to put it in the query? I have tried, but might have put it in the wrong place, if that matters?

Comment: You need to group by all columns you are selecting unless the column is in an aggregate function.

Comment: That gives me the following error: "Column 'INVENTABLE.ITEMNUMBER' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"

Comment: `INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER` not `INVENTABLE.ITEMNUMBER`, as you wanted to group those ;)

Comment: That is what I put :P If I change the column I'm selecting to "INVENTRANS.ITEMNUMBER" as well, it gives me the same error for "INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME1" o.o

Also @hello_world, would you try to explain? I'm not sure I understand :)

Comment: Then your INVENTABLE.ITEMNAME does not exist, as you are selecting it.. Check for spelling, in first post you have ITEMNAME1/ITEMNAME2

Comment: It does though, cause if I remove the `GROUP BY` again, it works just fine :(

Comment: updated answer, if your posted query works the one should work too

Comment: Appreciate the help, but I even copy pasted yours and it gives me the same error :/

Comment: @Mitch This *will* work in MySQL, but *doesn't* work in SQL Server. To make it work you have to include an aggregate function like `MIN`, `MAX` for every single field present in the `SELECT` clause that is not present in the `GROUP BY` clause.